# Set Default Font Type of WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, editor, wysiwyg

I am programming a WYSIWYG editor. I want the editor to have a default font of `Avenir Next`. However, no matter what I do, I cannot seem to be able to set the default font type of the content editable `iframe`. (I can include an option to change the highlighted text's font type, but that is not what I want. I want the font type to already be set to `Avenir Next` when I first type into the `iframe`.)

Below I've included the code for my `textarea` and `iframe`. Can someone give me the CSS or lines of javascript that will help me tackle this issue? Thank you!

```
<textarea  name = "content" id = "content" style = "display: none;" >
</textarea>
<iframe onload="iframe()" name = "editor" id = "editor" contenteditable="true" style = "width: 100%; height: 400;">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the font family property on the styles of that iframe, for example:

```
body { font-family: 'Avenir Next' }
```

Comment: That sets the default font of everything else to Avenir Next. However, the text that I type into the content editable iframe is still not this font. So I think this code does not apply to the content editable

Comment: What else do you have in your editor iframe? I would expect an iframe just for the editable text so it is fully isolated

Comment: Glad to help :)